# Regular expression to find 4 digits preceding by px or em or %

Tags: regex

I want to find 4 digits followed by `px` or `em` or `%`
last character may be a `;` or nothing.

In other words, I want to find padding and margin css attributes values

Consider digits may be negative or positive.

Example:

```
-2px 10em 2% -2;
------------------------
0 10px 5px -2%;
------------------------
5em 0 0 -8em;
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Specify the expected output and the programing language that you are using

Comment: well i want to find CSS' padding or margin values with 4 digits

Comment: in a css file i want to find all occurrences of padding and margin with 4 digits and replace left and right values with each other

Comment: for example find padding: -10% 0 2px 5%; and replace it with: padding -10% 5% 2px 0;

Comment: I am using dreamweaver search and replace regular expression

Comment: Please check if it works for you: https://regex101.com/r/uW8oG7/1. If not, please add more details (e.g. expected output for the sample input you provided) to the question itself, not as comments.

Comment: Or please check https://regex101.com/r/uW8oG7/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
(-?\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(-?\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(-?\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(-?\d+(?:px|em|%)?)
```

It's just `(-?\d+(?:px|em|%)?)` repeated 4 times with `\s+` in between (you can't just use `{4}` here because you need to capture the values).

The pattern is simple enough: optional minus sign (`-?`), followed by some digits (`\d+`), followed by an optional unit (`(?:px|em|%)?`).

Substitute this with `$1 $4 $3 $2` (or `\1 \4 \3 \2` - I don't know which one Drreamweaver uses).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hC7kG2/1)